# How to evaluate the value of a tensor, from inside the model function of a custom tf.estimator

Tags: tensorflow

I am implementing an NLP model based on BERT, using `tf.TPUEstimator()`. I want to implement layer-wise training, where I need to select only one layer of the model to train for each epoch. In order to do this I wanted to change my model_fn and get the value of current_epoch.

I know how to compute the value of current_epoch as a tensor using `tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()` inside the `model_fn` BUT, I need to evaluate the value of this tensor to select which layer to train and implement  return the correct `train_op` to the `tf.estimator` (**train_op pertaining to a single layer chosen accrding to the value of the current_epoch**).

I am unable to evaluate this tensor (current_epoch / global_step) from inside the model_fn. I tried the following but the training hangs at the step `my_sess.run(my_global_step.initializer`

```
global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
my_sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)
current_epoch = (global_step * full_bs) // train_size

my_sess.run(my_global_step.initializer)
current_epoch = sess.run(current_epoch)

# My program hangs at the initialising step: my_sess.run(my_global_step.initializer)
```

Is there any way to evaluate a tensor using the tf.Estimators default session? How do I get the default session/ Graph?

**Most importantly what is wrong in my code and why does the training hang when using tpu's and TPUEstimator**?

Comment: I have similar problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

This is not direct answer to OP's 2nd question, it is answer to the title.

I managed to print variable value with `get_variable_value`, but not sure if this is optimal way.

with

```py
estimator = tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimator(
# ...
)
out = estimator.get_variable_value('output_bias')
print(type(out))
print(out)
```

I got

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[-0.00107745  0.00107744]
```